# Passing ( cd / && ls ) command as variable to a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, unix

This is my bash script named `ooo`.

```
#!/bin/bash
$1
```

This command works great.

./ooo 'echo test'

The output is:

```
test
```

This command fails.

```
./ooo 'cd / && ls'
```

There is no output.

Why is there no output?

Comment: There is no output because cd is being invoked with 3 arguments, and it ignores the second two.

Comment: Furthermore see also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053

Comment: replace the `&&` with `;`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
eval "$1"
```

Comment: `bash -c "$1"` is less evil

Answer (score 2):

If your question is "how do I do what I expect to happen here?", then @ooga's answer is perfect.

If your question is "why doesn't this do what I expect?", then the answer is slightly more subtle.

What I think is happening (and the bash rules are intricate, so I'm not 100% positive here) is that

- The line `$1` is parsed as a one-word 'simple command' (see the bash manpage) – the one word is just `$1`, and the `&&` in the expansion isn't visible (and in particular doesn't do what you expected), because the parameter hasn't been expanded yet.
- That simple command is then split into words. Of course, there's only one 'word' here, so this step is trivial.
- The parameter is then expanded, to give the word "`cd / && ls`"
- Then "Word Splitting: The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion that did not occur within double quotes for word splitting." (bash manpage)
- Then this word is split into four words, "`cd`", "`/`", "`&&`" and "`ls`"
- Then "COMMAND EXECUTION:
     After a command has been split into words, if it results in a simple  command and an optional list of arguments, the following actions are taken.[...]"
- So the command `cd` is run with the three following words as arguments.  That means that, as William Pursell noted in his comment to your question, `cd` is given three arguments, two of which it ignores.

If you run your script with

```
./ooo 'echo / && ls'
```

you'll see this happening, and see the apparently magic `&&` being passed to the `echo` command as just a normal string.

Comment: I suspect variable expansion occurs after control operators are parsed, so the `&&` in the string is not seen by bash as a control operator

Comment: That's right.  The division into 'simple commands' – and thus the identification of `&&` as a control operator – is done once, early on in the parsing, and in particular before the parameter expansion.  Although word splitting is done a second time _after_ parameter expansion, there's no second scan for control operators, so `&&` stays as just a string.